# PHP While loop inside another and first while doesn't return other values

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, while-loop

I am a little bit confused about using while loop inside another. Everything is fine with the second loop but the first one only returns one value and it is the same.

```
$aukciono_laimetojai_while = mysql_query("SELECT id, user_id, date, win
    FROM tb_auction_winners WHERE user_id = 206");
$aukciono_istorija_while = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, aukciono_id,
    COALESCE(SUM(bid), 0) AS bid, date FROM tb_aukciono_istorija
    WHERE user_id = 206 GROUP BY aukciono_id");

while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($aukciono_istorija_while)) {
    while ($r2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($aukciono_laimetojai_while)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $r2['date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r2['win'] - $r1['bid']; ?> Eur</td>
            <td>0 Eur</td>
            <td>Plačiau <?php echo $r2['win'] . ' - ' . $r1['bid']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } } ?>
```

`$aukciono_laimetojai_while` returns:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHlQV.png)

`$aukciono_istorija_while` returns: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNA0U.png)

Using these 2 while loops, the table looks like this: (www.i.stack.imgur.com/Os8Rx.png) (can't use more than 2 links, sorry)

Something is wrong with the second number (0.14 should not be the same in every row, only the first one) and it should return 3 rows (`$r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($aukciono_istorija_while`) has 3 rows in the database). I do not know what is wrong here, using one while loop, everything is just fine. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: Yes, I know. I use `mysql_*` because the connection file using `mysql_*` and all script is quite old (PHP 5.6 version), so I can't use it :(

Comment: Store in array for each loop

Comment: Php 5.6 is not old.  Just after it,  7.0 was released

Comment: @Akintunde, can you explain more, please?

Comment: Can't you join the two tables

Comment: @Akintunde, yes but every script in the website uses `mysql_*`, so I should change everything.

Comment: @Akintunde I didn't think about the join, maybe that's the solution :)

Comment: Yes you should change every file which uses deprecated mysql_* functions. As soon as your provider switches to PHP7 your script won 't run anymore.

Comment: @Marcel Yes, I know, it's a lot to do here. Should I change it just because it is deprecated or non-secure?

Comment: Should I use join here?

Comment: Use mysql_fetch_array for mysql_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I should use only one query in the while loop. Instead of this block of code:

```
$aukciono_laimetojai_while = mysql_query("SELECT id, user_id, date, win
    FROM tb_auction_winners WHERE user_id = 206");
$aukciono_istorija_while = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, aukciono_id,
    COALESCE(SUM(bid), 0) AS bid, date FROM tb_aukciono_istorija
    WHERE user_id = 206 GROUP BY aukciono_id");

while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($aukciono_istorija_while)) {
    while ($r2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($aukciono_laimetojai_while)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $r2['date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r2['win'] - $r1['bid']; ?> Eur</td>
            <td>0 Eur</td>
            <td>Plačiau <?php echo $r2['win'] . ' - ' . $r1['bid']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } } ?>
```

I should use this (1 query, 1 while loop):

```
$aukciono_laimetojai_ir_aukciono_istorija_while = mysql_query("
SELECT tai.aukciono_id tai_aukciono_id, taw.win taw_win, taw.date taw_date,
    COALESCE(SUM(tai.bid), 0) tai_bid FROM tb_auction_winners taw
JOIN tb_aukciono_istorija tai ON taw.id = tai.aukciono_id
WHERE tai.user_id = $usid GROUP BY aukciono_id");

while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($aukciono_laimetojai_ir_aukciono_istorija_while)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $r1['taw_date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r1['taw_win'] - $r1['tai_bid']; ?> Eur</td>
            <td>0 Eur</td>
            <td class="placiau" data-aukciono-id=
                "<?php echo $r1['tai_aukciono_id']; ?>">Plačiau</td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
```